Plot Rectangles Denoting Sections
How do I plot "rectangles" with some level of transparency (alpha value) to be overlaid on a line plot? Each rectangle would denote a section or phase. I have the x-axis indices where each section starts and ends. I'd like the rectangle to vertically fill the figure within its horizontal range. See example below.


Duplicate of Overlay Shaded Regions on a Line Plot Based on Conditions

IUC, you can define a list of colors and of boundaries, then use axvspan:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import pairwise

regions = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
colors = ['#ECECEA', '#BDD3DD', '#E68892', '#7FD7A7']

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(np.random.random(size=20))

for (x1, x2), c in zip(pairwise(regions), colors):
    ax.axvspan(x1, x2, color=c, ls='', alpha=0.5)

Output:

With the labels:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import pairwise

regions = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
colors = ['#ECECEA', '#BDD3DD', '#E68892', '#7FD7A7']

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(np.random.random(size=20))

for i, ((x1, x2), c) in enumerate(zip(pairwise(regions), colors), start=1):
    ax.axvspan(x1, x2, color=c, ls='', alpha=0.5)
    ax.text((x1+x2)/2, ax.get_ylim()[0],
            f'Phase {i}', ha='center', va='bottom')

Output:

